# For loop skips rows in R dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a for loop printing values out of this small test dataframe.

```
      USA    Finland    China    Sweden
1     1      3         5.505962  8.310596
2     2      4        11.033347  5.425747
3     3      5        14.932882  3.272544
4     4      6        10.155517  5.980190
5     5      7        11.020148  3.692313
Total 0      0         0.000000  0.000000
```

This line prints out a line from the dataframe:

```
print(countries[2,])
```

and results in this:

```
    USA Finland    China   Sweden
2   2   4        11.03335  5.425747
```

So based on that, I imagine I could do the same in a for loop and print out all the lines. Code for the loop:

```
for (i in countries[1,])
{    
    print(countries[i,])
}
```

However this results in only every second line printed out which doesn't make sense. The result I get is this:

```
    USA Finland    China   Sweden
1   1   3         5.505962 8.310596
    USA Finland    China   Sweden
3   3   5         14.93288 3.272544
    USA Finland    China   Sweden
5   5   7         11.02015 3.692313
    USA Finland    China   Sweden
NA  NA  NA         NA      NA
```

What could possibly lead to this happening? I'm using R studio so could it be the console logging not keeping up with the values?

Comment: Use `for(i in 1:5)` or `for(i in 1:nrow(countries))` as the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lmo comment suggest solution. I think that you want to know why this happend, so I'll try to answer that.

You are using this code:

```
1: for (i in countries[1,])
2: {    
3:     print(countries[i,])
4: }
```

In line `1` you are selecting a vector of values that `i` will be using. This vector happens to be the first row of your data: `1 3 5.505962 8.310596`. It translates to a vector `c(1,3,5,8)` - as indexes.

So in line `3` you are printing lines `1, 3, 5, 8` (because you choose that indexes). It was quite random that it were even rows, but I hope you understand it better.

Of course you should use `df[1:5,]` or `print(df)` instead of `for`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Kinda ridiculous luck that the values happened to be every second line.. and the for loop exists because I was going to do more than just printing the values, calculating total of each column for example